# param of a function in Parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I am following this tutorial http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/meteor-methods

so having :

```
import {Parties} from './parties';

function getContactEmail(user: Meteor.User): string {
    if (user.emails && user.emails.length)
        return user.emails[0].address;

    return null;
};

Meteor.methods({
    invite: function(partyId: string, userId: string) {
        check(partyId, String);
        check(userId, String);

        let party = Parties.findOne(partyId);

        if (!party)
            throw new Meteor.Error('404', 'No such party!');

        if (party.public)
            throw new Meteor.Error('400', 'That party is public. No need to invite people.');

        if (party.owner !== this.userId)
            throw new Meteor.Error('403', 'No permissions!');

        if (userId !== party.owner && (party.invited || []).indexOf(userId) == -1) {
            Parties.update(partyId, { $addToSet: { invited: userId } });

            let from = getContactEmail(Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId));
            let to = getContactEmail(Meteor.users.findOne(userId));

            if (Meteor.isServer && to) {
                Email.send({
                    from: 'noreply@socially.com',
                    to: to,
                    replyTo: from || undefined,
                    subject: 'PARTY: ' + party.name,
                    text: `Hi, I just invited you to ${party.name} on Socially.
                        \n\nCome check it out: ${Meteor.absoluteUrl()}\n`
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
invite(user: Meteor.User) {
        this.call('invite', this.party._id, user._id, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                alert(`Failed to invite due to ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            alert('User successfully invited.');
        });
    }
```

I can't understand the `(error) => {`, From where does the error value come?

Comment: see http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ES6 `(args) => {` is shorthand way of defining a function [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

so

```
invite(user: Meteor.User) {
        this.call('invite', this.party._id, user._id, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                alert(`Failed to invite due to ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            alert('User successfully invited.');
        });
    }
```

would be the same as

```
invite(user: Meteor.User) {
        this.call('invite', this.party._id, user._id, function(error){
            if (error) {
                alert(`Failed to invite due to ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            alert('User successfully invited.');
        });
    }
```